# Android - A frame animation at Dialog, by a press of a button - not working

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a dialog with animation be shown when a button being pressed.

In oredr to do so -

1)I've create a xml file which I've call it progress_animation.xml - 
this is the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lodaing1" android:duration="305" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lodaing2" android:duration="305" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lodaing3" android:duration="305" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lodaing4" android:duration="305" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lodaing5" android:duration="305" />
</animation-list>
```

as you can see I'm using few png files in order to make it a frame animation.

2)I've made a layout xml file for the dialog - here's the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loading_anim_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

3) I've made an activity and it's layout contains a button. When the button being press i want the animation to start.

In order to do so , here's the activity code -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){


    case R.id.button1:


        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_activity);
         ImageView load = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.loading_anim_view);
         load.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_animation);

         AnimationDrawable loadingnimation = (AnimationDrawable) load.getBackground();

         dialog.show();
         loadingnimation.start();


        break;


    }


}
```

}

Well my problem is that i only get to see the first frame - pic file - but not seeing the next frames -.

Any idea why?
Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_activity);
     ImageView load = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.loading_anim_view);   // Correction here
     load.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_animation);
```

Comment: Well now the app not crashing, but the animation dosen't work - I only see the first frame of it but not the next frames - got any idea why maybe?

Comment: @4this What animation is that i didn't understand that sorry.

Comment: @4this hope you haven't missed any of the following steps after @Hariharan 's code : `dialog.show();
        AnimationDrawable loadAnim= (AnimationDrawable) load.getBackground();

        loadAnim.start();`